# Is there a principled way to compose two monad transformers if they are of different type, but their underlying monad is of the same type?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Not much I can do to expand the question. But here is a use case: let's say you have two monad transformers, `t` and `s`, transforming over the same monad `m`:

```
master :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => t m a b
slave  :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => s m a b
```

And I want to compose `master` and `slave` such that they can communicate with each other when `m` primitives are lifted into `t` and `s`. The signature might be:

```
bound :: (MonadTrans t, MonadTrans s, Monad m, Monoid a) => t m a b -> s m a b -> (...)
But what is the type of (...) ?
```

A use case, in sugared notation:

```
master :: Monoid a => a -> t m a b
master a = do 
   a <- lift . send $ (a,False)     -- * here master is passing function param to slave
   ...                              -- * do some logic with a
   b <- lift . send $ (mempty,True) -- * master terminates slave, and get back result

slave :: Monoid a => (a -> b) -> s m a b
slave g = do 
    (a,end) <- lift receive
    case end of 
        True -> get >>= \b -> exit b  
        _    -> (modify (++[g a])) >> slave g
```

Update: `send` and `receive` are primitives of type `m`.

I apologize if this example looks contrived, or resemble coroutines too much, the spirit of the question really has nothing to do with it so please ignore all similarities. But main point is that monads `t` and `s` couldn't be sensibly composed with each other before, but after both wrap some underlying monad `m`, they now could be composed and run as a single function. As for the type of the composed function, I'm really not sure so some direction is appreciated. Now if this abstraction already exist and I just don't know about it, then that would be best.

Comment: Are `s` and `t` arbitrary or are they somehow specific - are we trying to create such `s` and `t`? And the same question applies to `m` - how about it and its `send` and `receive`?

Comment: Yes `s` and `t` are arbitrary. `m` is the specific type we are trying to create here. `send` and `receive` are just primitive functions of type `(a,Bool) -> m a b` and `m a b` respectively. But they're incidental to the contrived use case I gave, the details of their implementation are not important.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  Combine `hoist` from the `mmorph` package with `lift` to do this:

```
bound
    :: (MonadTrans t, MonadTrans s, MFunctor t, Monad m)
    => t m () -> s m () -> t (s m) ()
bound master slave = do
    hoist lift master
    lift slave
```

To understand why this works, study the type of `hoist`:

```
hoist :: (MFunctor t) => (forall x . m x -> n x) -> t m r -> t n r
```

`hoist` lets you modify the base monad of any monad transformer that implements `MFunctor` (which is most of them).

What the code for `bound` does is have the two monad transformers agree on a final target monad, which in this case is `t (s m)`.  The order in which you nest `t` and `s` is up to you, so I just assumed that you wanted `t` on the outside.

Then it's just a matter of using various combinations of `hoist` and `lift` to get the two sub-computations to agree on the final monad stack.  The first one works like this:

```
master :: t m r
hoist lift master :: t (s m) r
```

The second one works like this:

```
slave :: s m r
lift slave :: t (s m) r
```

Now they both agree so we can sequence them within the same `do` block and it will "just work".

To learn more about how `hoist` works, I recommend you check [the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mmorph/1.0.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Morph.html) for the `mmorph` package which has [a nice tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mmorph/1.0.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Morph.html#g:3) at the bottom.